# Call C# method from javascript drag and drop event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery which does drag and drop -

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $(".drag-div").droppable({
            accept: ".draggable",
            tolerance: "pointer",
            activeClass: "drop-here",
            hoverClass: "drop-here-hover",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $.fancybox({
                    href: '#add-quantity'                            
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to be able to get the text value of what I have just dragged and dropped, then call a C# method which requires that parameter to alter a database table. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a web service method, you can do this in your same page and then use ajax to call this method. Here is a sample of this:

- [Web Method Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-jQuery-to-directly-05c25592)
- [calling asmx web service method with jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125153/calling-asmx-web-service-method-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Jquery Ajax and then create an asmx or a WebApi.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using asp.net mvc? I think you could look for SignalR to do that.

So, if you think is to much, the simplest way could be to create one like ondrop.aspx and call it by some ajax method:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $(".drag-div").droppable({
            accept: ".draggable",
            tolerance: "pointer",
            activeClass: "drop-here",
            hoverClass: "drop-here-hover",
            drop: function (event, ui) {

                var $div = $(ui.draggable); // here access the dragging div
                var param = $div.text();
                $.post('ondrop.aspx', { someparam: param }).done(function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });

                $.fancybox({
                    href: '#add-quantity'                            
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

See? In that point you have access to the dragging element, and you just have to select wich attribute you will need and then make a ajax call to some .aspx page. So you treat that page using Request.Form["someparam"]; and result a clean json from that.

Comment: You can use also, take a look. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526876/AddingplusSignalRplustoplusanplusASP-NetplusWebFor

SignalR allows you to do realtime events, from client to server, and even from server to client.

Comment: Plus MVC is not a pre-requisite for using SignalR.

Comment: @MattBaughan - Why are you using javascript in WinForms?

Comment: The template I have been given uses javascript for the drag and drop. I have been asked to make it modify a SQL database.